# boto3 python - list objects

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

While trying to list objects with a prefix, the return is only fetching only 1 object in my Lambda. Not sure what is missing.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:  
        ## Bucket to use
        bucket = s3.Bucket(mybucket)
        ## List objects within a given prefix
        for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='output/group1'):
            print(obj.key)
```

Comment: You code is incomplete and not running. For example `mybucket` is not assigned.
Try to test your boto3 code locally before deploying as lambda.

Comment: Hi Wolfgang .. I have it defined but i eliminated that line when uploading the code.

Comment: BTW, i am running into some other issue when i run boto3 locally. It is not able to find my credential even though it's present in aws cli credential file. i check my profile do exist in both config and credentials . Ran aws configure multiple times.

Comment: This code defines a function `lambda_handler` but it is never called.  Where/how is it called?

Comment: Where does the output of `print` appear?  In aws cloudwatch?

Comment: correct. Everything goes to Cloudwatch. This is part of lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what the exact problem is when we can't see a valid function or any returned errors. This code works without issue for me:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = s3.Bucket('your-bucket-name')
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='output/group1'):
        print(obj.key)
lambda_handler('event','context')
```

Make sure 'output/group1' actually has more than 1 file in it to return.

Comment: The code runs without error but it's not giving the list of all the objects, just 1 object with that prefix. There are 30+ objects with same prefix.

Comment: @Ryan Are you sure that you have access to those specific S3 keys?

Comment: Yes. I get a random one of the key, but not all the keys.

Comment: @Ryan The code is correct. You have to double check your s3 bucket structure and its prefixes.

Comment: what happens when you add the trailing / in the Prefix? 'output/group1/'

Comment: Thank you Marcin and Jonathan. That helped and now it gives me the list.